# Comparing two PorterDuffColorFilter objects

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-graphics

I am in need of comparing two **PorterDuffColorFilter** objects to check if a `ProgressBar` is displaying the correct color in an **Espresso Test**

I have tried comparing the two objects directly, but the following method always returns `false`:

```
// Creating a PorterDuffColorFilter Object
weakOrNonePasswordColorFilter =
            new PorterDuffColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(mActivityRule.getActivity(), R.color.red), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
...

// Retrieving the ProgressBar ColorFilter and compare
public boolean matchesSafely(ProgressBar progressBar, PorterDuffColorFilter colorFilter) {
  LayerDrawable drawable = (LayerDrawable) progressBar.getProgressDrawable();
  Drawable progressDrawable = drawable.getDrawable(1);
  progressDrawable.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
  return ((PorterDuffColorFilter)progressDrawable.getColorFilter()).equals(colorFilter);
}
```

Looking into the `PorterDuffColorFilter` there is a

```
public int getColor() {
    return mColor;
}
```

Method that should solve my problem. However, I cannot access this method. Android Studio only displays the "Object" methods, and if I try to compile the app with the .`getColor()` an error message is displayed stating that the method could not be found.

Is this problem occurring due to the fact that this class is in `android.graphics` package, making it inaccessible?

If so, how can I retrieve the color of the `ProgressBar` bar and compare it with a Color?

Comment: could you please share your code so we could help?

Comment: you can extend `PorterDuffColorFilter` but honestly your problem smells like [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: If so, how can I test in an Espresso test that the progressBar has the correct color?

Comment: `getColor()` is `@hide`n so [this](https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api) can help - you can also use custom `PorterDuffColorFilter` in your tests

Answer (score 1):

PorterDuffColorFilter overrides `equals` so you should be able to use: `filterA.equals(filterB)`

```
// From PorterDuffColorFilter.java

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (this == object) {
        return true;
    }
    if (object == null || getClass() != object.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final PorterDuffColorFilter other = (PorterDuffColorFilter) object;
    return (mColor == other.mColor && mMode.nativeInt == other.mMode.nativeInt);
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this (edited the original post) but unfortunately this is not working since it always returns false.

Comment: Clever solution, thank you.  It worked for me.  @Vanethos to make it work, I had to step into the equals() in the debugger to figure out exactly how to make it equal.  In my case, one issue was that I had passed `imageView.getColorFilter()` when it needed `imageView.getDrawable().getColorFilter()` for my particular case.